# Putting module in modal box Joomla

Tags: joomla, modal-dialog

Is it possible to display Joomla module in a modal box? I try putting module in article by using loadposition and in another article I put

```
<a class="modal" href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=18" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 640, y: 480}}">auto</a>
```

but I get not only module but all page. I try to display subscriber form of Communicator Module (http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/newsletter/4600).

Maybe should I change something in this module to display it in a correct way using modal box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some small trick...you have to assign a id to the container of the module Div, and add this id in the url so the url can load the module..

```
<div id='Modulecontainer'>
<module>
</div>

<a class="modal" href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=18#Modulecontainer" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 640, y: 480}}">auto</a>
```

I have use the same here in looking for land page where the search result is shown in google map.
[farmleaseconnection.org/](http://farmleaseconnection.org/%27)

Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: Thank you Pramod Kumar Sharma

Comment: @Pramod: could you please describr this in more detail? How do you "assign a id to the container of the module Div"?

Answer (score 0):

Joomla itself has not facility for this, and if your template doesn't have it built in (like many RocketTheme templates) there is an extensions called [JQPopup](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/popups-a-iframes/16923) that handles it quite nicely.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have on my side mootools and I would rather not to use jquery.

Comment: Found this one too that only uses mootools: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/popups-a-iframes/6123

Comment: It seems you've changed the question a bit, so none of these may be necessary.  It sounds like you're going about it the right way, but you're getting "too much" of the content page.  Have you tried changing the paramters like hiding the heading, author, etc.  You havent' said exactly what IS being displayed that you don't want to be.